# sys.dm_os_volume_stats return no result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Version - SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU3.

I have been using [sys.dm_os_volume_stats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223223.aspx) for a while and it was working. Recently I have not been able to return any result from this DMF on one SQL Server 2012 instance.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_volume_stats(1, 1);
```

I have no issues with the same code on other SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2008 R2 instances. Does anyone know the reason behind and has fixed this problem?

Comment: does this still give you no results? `
select d.name, d.type, d.physical_name, vfs.*
 from sys.master_files d 
  OUTER apply sys.dm_os_volume_stats(d.database_id, d.file_id) vfs;`

Comment: What user are you connected as? Are you sure you have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions?

Comment: @swasheck I was using similar type of query like yours and it was returning NULL on columns from this DMF. Issue is that the DMF doesn't return any result.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes. I was using an account with sysadmin role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, in order for the DMF to work, it appears that the service account needs to have at least READ access to the root volume of where the database files are located at, in addition to the SQL Server login security VIEW SERVER STATE permission.

The READ permission does not have to be granted explicitly to the service account. It could be granted through other user/groups,

1) SQL Server service account
2) Everyone
3) Users
4) NT Authority\Authenticated Users

The idea is SQL Server service account needs at least READ permission to the root volume. I have listed the test and details [here](http://www.travisgan.com/2013/11/sql-dmv-sysdmosvolumestats-not.html).